# globbing, sed, or awk html files

Tags: sed, awk, html

I wanted to create a script that I could check `.xhtml` files for images and add alt tags if needed.  While searching I found regular expressions and did man on `glob` but I'm unsure on where or what to search within `awk` and `sed`.  What would be the best option to do the following:

```
<img class="something" width="something" height="something" src="folder/folder/image.png" />

<img id="something" src="folder/folder/file.png" />
```

I wanted the desired script to detect if an `alt=""` is present if not alt the file name.

End desired format:

```
<img class="something" width="something" height="something" src="folder/folder/image.png" alt="image"/>

<img id="something" src="folder/folder/file.png" alt="file"/>
```

I know it can be done but Im not sure where to read about it.

- Find `<img` with the ending `/>`
- Within `img` tag detect `alt=""`
- if `alt=""` is not present record name before file type and insert into `""`

Comment: Just a warning: it is not possible to parse XML-type languages reliably with regular expressions as XML is not a regular language.  The best you can do is an ad-hoc approximation for a restricted subset of valid (X)HTML.  It'd help if you could list as many characteristics of your input as possible.  E.g. does the string `<img` occur outside the context of a valid image tag anywhere?  How about `alt=`?  Can tags span multiple lines?  Complications like this are what make the problem impossible unless you place some additional restrictions on it.

Comment: I wouldn't know where to begin.  I just need to find a way to identify all `img` tags and make sure an `alt` tag is present

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way using `perl` with the help of the `XML::Twig` parser:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;
use File::Spec;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers => {

        ## For each 'img' tag execute following function...
        'img' => sub {

            ## If it doesn't have an 'alt' attribute...
            if ( ! $_->att_exists( 'alt' ) ) { 

                ## Get value of 'src' tag.
                my $src = $_->att( 'src' );
                return unless $src;

                ## Get last part of the path and remove extension.
                my $src_file = (File::Spec->splitpath( $src ))[2] || q{};
                $src_file =~ s/\.[^.]+$//;

                ## Create the 'alt' attribute.
                $_->set_att( 'alt', $src_file );
            }   
        }   
    },  
    pretty_print => 'indented',
)->parsefile( shift )->print;
```

Run it with your `xml` file as unique argument, like:

```
perl script.pl xmlfile
```